# PHP Replace the very first lower cased char of every line by upper case

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I've tried using the below

```
$string= 'hello world<br>this is newline<br><br>another line';
echo $string.'<hr><br>';
echo preg_replace_callback('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/m', function($m) {
  return strtoupper($m[0]);
}, $string);
```

the output:

```
Hello world
this is newline

another line
```

i need to change the first letter of word "this" and "another" too. so the output become like this:

```
Hello world
This is newline

Another line
```

Thanks.

Comment: `<br>` is not a new line in anything except a browser/application that is rendering HTML. You could try `/(^|<br>)` or convert them to new lines. Also a `.` would probably be easier than a character class unless you only want to capitalize `a-z` (if that is case character class can be trimmed down to `[a-z]`).

Comment: And why include `A-Z` and `0-9`?  What are their uppercases?

Comment: You can change your regex to [`(?:^|<[bh]r>)\s*\K[a-z]`](https://www.regex101.com/r/Xxfnub/1) (see explanation on regex 101). Here is a [PHP demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/748045).

Comment: @bobblebubble glad you came here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve what you want:

```
$string= 'hello world<br>this is newline<br><br>another line<hr><br>';

$parts = preg_split( "/<br>|<hr>/", $string ); // split string by either <br> or <hr>
$parts = array_filter($parts); // clean array from empty values
$parts = array_map('ucfirst',$parts); // array of lines with first letter capitalized

echo $partString = implode("<br>",$parts);
```